# Accept track changes and convert .doc to .txt using CATDOC

Tags: python, text, doc

How can I accept the track changes while converting a .doc file to .txt file using catdoc?

Suppose there are two files 'original.doc' and 'modified.doc'.

'original.doc' has the following sentence:`this a test sentence`
 
'modified.doc' has the following sentence: `this is a test statement`

When i convert the modified.doc to a .txt file instead of getting `this is a test statement` I'm getting `this is a test sentence statement`

I'm using the code below.

```
def doc_to_text_catdoc(filename):
(fi, fo, fe) = os.popen3('catdoc -w "%s"' % filename)
fi.close()
retval = fo.read()
erroroutput = fe.read()
fo.close()
fe.close()
if not erroroutput:
    return retval
else:
    raise OSError("Executing the command caused an error: %s" % erroroutput)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by using Antiword.

```
(fi, fo, fe) = os.popen3('antiword -f "%s"' % filename)
```